# AKS cluster creating additional route table, additional NSG and its not using existing custom route table and NSG

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I've recently started working on terraform with azure. As part of it i've gone through the documentation as much as possible to create resources. in this i'm trying to create AKS cluster. I was able to created successfully. but i've few concerns( which i felt bugs, correct if i'm wrong).

At present during AKS cluster provision, aks-engine will create route table & Network security automatically. i don't see any option to prevent these in terraform documentaion. As i wanted use existing route-table and NSG as because i'm under corporate network.
expected behavior : ASK should pick existing route table and NSG instead of creating new resources.
here is my code snippet. kindly help me.

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "~> 2.15"
    features {}
 }

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks" {
    name     = var.resource_group
    location = var.location
}
#fetch existing subnet 
data "azurerm_subnet" "aks" {
    name                 = var.subnetname
    virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name
    resource_group_name  = var.vnet_resource_group
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "aks" {
    subnet_id                 = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
    network_security_group_id = var.network_security_group
}

resource "azurerm_route_table" "aks"{
    name                          = var.subnetname
    resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    location                      = azurerm_resource_group.aks.location
    disable_bgp_route_propagation = false

    route{
        name                = var.route_name
        address_prefix      = var.route_address_prefix
        next_hop_type       = var.route_next_hop_type
    }

}
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "aks" {
    subnet_id      = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
    route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.aks.id
}
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
    name                    = azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    location                = azurerm_resource_group.aks.location
    dns_prefix              = "akstfpoc"   #The dns_prefix must contain between 3 and 45 characters, and can contain only letters, numbers, and hyphens. It must start with a letter and must end with a letter or a number.
    kubernetes_version      = "1.15.10"
    private_cluster_enabled = false
    node_resource_group     = var.node_resource_group
    
    api_server_authorized_ip_ranges = [] #var.api_server_authorized_ip_ranges
    default_node_pool {
        enable_node_public_ip   = false
        name                    = "agentpool" 
        node_count              = var.node_count
        orchestrator_version    = "1.15.10"
        vm_size                 = var.vm_size
        os_disk_size_gb         = var.os_disk_size_gb
        vnet_subnet_id          = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
    }

    linux_profile {
        admin_username = var.admin_username
        ssh_key {
            key_data = var.ssh_key
        }
    }
    service_principal {
        client_id     = var.client_id
        client_secret = var.client_secret
    }

    role_based_access_control {
        enabled = true
    }
    network_profile {
        network_plugin = "kubenet"
        #dns_service_ip     = "172.17.1.10"
        #service_cidr       = "172.16.0.0/14"
        pod_cidr           = "172.40.0.0/16"
        network_policy     = "calico"
        outbound_type      = "loadBalancer"
        load_balancer_sku  = "Standard"


        # load_balancer_profile {
        #     managed_outbound_ip_count = []
        #     outbound_ip_address_ids   = []
        #     outbound_ip_prefix_ids    = [""]
            
        # }
    }
            addon_profile {
            aci_connector_linux {
            enabled = false
        }

        azure_policy {
            enabled = false
        }

        http_application_routing {
            enabled = false
        }

        kube_dashboard {
            enabled = false
        }

        oms_agent {
            enabled = false
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: are you referring to address space and subnet of the AKS VNET ?

Comment: Yes I'm using existing Subnet from different vnet @Jawad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a private Subnet, you should use the

network_plugin = "azure"

this will allow you to tie your AKS cluster to a pre existing Subnet which you will have full control over the Route Table and the NSG (you can pre create them and associated them with your subnet with Terraform)

Have a look at the documentation on how to use the azure-cli

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni

for Terraform you will need to set

vnet_subnet_id on the default_agent_pool: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html#vnet_subnet_id

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html#network_profile

Comment: Thank you @djsly's . But my requirement need to get above with kubenet plugin. Is there any other way to achieve?

Comment: it is, have a look at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-kubenet#bring-your-own-subnet-and-route-table-with-kubenet

Comment: Thank you so much @djsly . Now i can able to provision the cluster with UDR successfully .. the above docs really good.

Comment: Perfect. Please accept this answer if this is acceptable.